# The true size of something when 'on the fly' moving around in EPSG:3857

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, web-mercator

I know this should be a trivial question, but I still will ask it as I have a knot it my head...

The Web Mercator is distorting shapes and areas further from the equator. This is why Greenland is so big on a static world map.

When I would drag down greenland over the equator in QGIS, the size is still way too big. I am wondering why. I imagined that the distortion in size would have been compensated by it being closer to the Equator now?

I guess it is the initial size it has on a Web Mercator map that makes it so wrong, even when interactively dragging it further south?!

[image]

Comment: If you had translated the angular units that would have worked, but translating the exaggerated "meters" can't work.

Comment: See this very similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/393558/88814